# Unable to locate element method using find element by Xpath in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I want to type 0.5 into the "mintMultiple: Input". I have tried finding element by Xpath using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Main\Documents\Work\Projects\Scraping Websites\extra\chromedriver')

my_url = "https://etherscan.io/address/0x6eed5b7ec85a802428f7a951d6cc1523181c776a#writeContract"

driver.get(my_url)
time.sleep(2)
your_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//input[@id="input_payable_3_mintMultiple"]')
```

However, I get this Error, I've tried using a delay and not using a delay as suggested by other sources, but I get the same error.

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id="input_payable_3_mintMultiple"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)
```

This shows the Xpath is correct as it highlighted in yellow in the HTML.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x6eed5b7ec85a802428f7a951d6cc1523181c776a#writeContract
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element is within an [*`<iframe>`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447). So you have to switch to the frame and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.get("https://etherscan.io/address/0x6eed5b7ec85a802428f7a951d6cc1523181c776a#writeContract")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#btnCookie"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#writecontractiframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "3. mintMultiple"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#input_payable_3_mintMultiple"))).send_keys("0.5")
```

- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: mintMultiple]

Answer (score 1):

This is because the **input is hidden within the drop-down tab** and does not show up under the HTML. In order for the element to be interactable, you must first click on the drop down tab. Add the following line of code before "your_input" variable:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='heading3']/a").click() #dropdown tab
```

Furthermore to complete the code:

```
your_input.click()
your_input.send_keys("0.5")
```

Comment: I got this error 'NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="heading3"]/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)'

Comment: @user13174343 Just saw my error! Change "heading3" to 'heading3'

Comment: error still persists

Comment: @user13174343 working on it